# swift 3 ios : convert UInt8 Array to int8

Tags: ios, swift3, uint8array

i have an UInt8 array that contains values between 0 and 255

i would like to convert this array to Int8 array in order to contains values between -128 and 127

How to achieve this in swift?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can convert a [UInt8] to a [Int8] by using this:

```
for el in uint8Array {
    uint8Array.append(UInt8(bitPattern: el))
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Use `map` and the appropriate initialiser:

```
let intArray = uintArray.map { Int8(bitPattern: $0) }
```

Comment: `map(Int8.init)`